# Regex for UK phone number

Tags: regex

I need to validate uk numbers

Below are sample type of number

```
01457 341235
0229  111111
```

+1213 3133143

Optional Plus should be allowed at first postion only

Using this regex but not working

```
^(?:\W*\d){11}\W*$
```

Comment: Why do you have non-word character pattern (\W*) added there?

Comment: As I dont need a character in phone number

Comment: So some non-word character can come there? That's what you meant?

Comment: No only brackets () can come

Comment: Brackets and spaces can come anywhere in the number?

Comment: like this (020) xxxx xxxx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An [actual UK phone number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom) will start with 0 or +44 (the latter being the UK country code), or possibly just 44, followed by nine or ten digits.  A regex to capture that would look something like:

```
^(?:0|\+?44)(?:\d\s?){9,10}$
```

In this regex, I have allowed the digits to be separated by spaces in any way, because there isn't a single standardized way of breaking down the numbers. You could further narrow this down to certain allowed groupings, if you like, but it would greatly increase the complexity of the regex.

Your question implies you might want something broader or different.  As some of your examples aren't valid UK numbers (`+1213 3133143`, `12345 123456`).

You could use something like this to simply match between 10 and 12 digits, with arbitrary spacing, possibly preceded by a +:

```
^\+?(?:\d\s?){10,12}$
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying..but I am trying your regex on http://regexr.com/ but it is not matching the above phone number tried this ^\+?(?:\d\s?){10,12}$

Comment: @HDev007 my regex allows only a single space between groups of digits, but one of your examples above has two spaces.  You could change it to `\s*` instead of `\s?` if you want to allow an arbitrary number of spaces between groups.  Also note that regexr.com treats everything there like a single string...it doesn't consider each line as a separate match.  So you would have to enter a single number at a time for testing.

Comment: very true.Thanks dan for your explanations.:) It works fine.

Comment: @dan1111 or just turn on the multiline.

Comment: Looking at https://www.area-codes.org.uk/formatting.php - UK land line numbers are far more complex than the assumptions here. If anyone's got a good link to a validator that will only pass truly valid numbers, I'd love to see it.